# Limit sessions in spring boot with redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring boot with Redis to authenticate users.

My application authenticates user for the first time with username & password and sends back an unique token. For further transactions, user sends the token in header.

This works well, but I do not want spring to create a new token when an user is already authenticated and has a token in Redis.

Setup: Spring Boot : 1.4.0; Java 1.8

I did try the below and it isn't working.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{   
  @Autowired
  private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

  @Bean
  public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() 
  {
     return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
  }

   @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
  {
     auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
  {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()                       
        .and()
        .requestCache()
        .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
  }


  @Bean
  public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() 
  {
     SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
     return sessionRegistry;
  }

  @Bean
  public static HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() 
  {
     return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }   
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return the existing valid token to this user or deny login?

Comment: @amantsingh Return existing token. I'd like to know both.

Comment: Please share the code of custom authentication handler and part where you are setting the token in Redis.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        // other config goes here...
                        .sessionManagement()
                                .maximumSessions(1)
                                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        }

        @Bean
        SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
                return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(this.sessionRepository);
        }
}
```

More detail see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#spring-security-concurrent-sessions)

Comment: I did try this as well, but did not work. This could work for oob spring sessions. Can you confirm if this works for spring with Redis as well? Each time I send the same username & password, it returns new token and all the tokens are accepted.

Comment: so why you use the `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`